# concat strings in .rc file

Tags: winapi, resources

I have .rc file with string definition

```
#define PATH "C:\\Program Files\\My"
#define FILE "file.txt"

#define HTML 23

file.txt HTML PATH+"\\"+FILE      <--- how to write properly?
```

Comment: Use the preprocessor's token pasting operator, ##

Answer (score 2):

You might try it the C style, so just writing

```
PATH "\\" FILE
```

but I do not really expect it to work. Even if that is accepted by the resource compiler I doubt that the Resource Editor will accept such code.